# Pass Fields to Subreports in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I am using Jasper-Reports 5.2.0 and have a main Report containing 2 sub-reports.

I have a Model `ReportData` which contains two attributes: `List<Feld> felder` and `List<Wert> werte`. The two sub-models contain multiple attributes with data to be displayed in a table.

So this is how I pass my Datasource to the sub-reports.

```
<subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="28" width="553" height="51" uuid="502d9559-e6bf-49c8-a34c-ffb8916634cd"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F(werte)]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA["werte_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>

<subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="555" height="50" uuid="5e5b0287-5002-4e31-aa8f-afe36ea78827"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F(felder))]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA["felder_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

and this is how I fill my report (datasource is the Collection of `ReportData`):

```
printable = JasperFillManager.fillReport(PropertyLoader.getSingleton().loadAsInputStream(REPORT_FOLDER + File.separatorChar + KONFIG_JASPER),parameters, datasource);
```

Somehow my values are not passed to the sub-reports and Jasper Reports is trying to use attributes as `defaultWert`, which isn't part of the Class `Wert` and should be displayed in the sub-report.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : defaultWert
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'defaultWert' on class XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.model.ReportData'
```

I defined the two Lists `werte` and `felder` as fields of type `java.util.List` in the Main Report and defined the attributes as for `defaultWert` as fields of type String in the sub-reports. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is tagged with the iText tag. JasperReports uses an obsolete version of iText and AFAIK there is currently no business relationship whatsoever between iText and JasperSoft/TIBCO. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: I was not aware of that non-existing relationship. I used the tag because it is used in many questions that i looked through before i asked this one.

Comment: @shuricano Can you add how you create the datasource to your question. Also do you have a field called `defaultWert` defined in the main report or the sub-reports? My general troubleshooting steps for these things, is to remove the sub-reports, and make sure the main report works correctly. Than add back one sub-report at a time so I can find the one report in particular that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Bruno It is a stupid point, but I am not sure the iText community is actually bigger than the JasperReports community. I mean there are 4800+ jasper-reports questions and 2700+ itext questions here on SO. You are correct that this question has nothing to do with itext. But you statement just seemed condescending. As for as the the iText version jasper reports uses being obsolete, it seems to work pretty well for all of us using jasper reports. Maybe if they had not changed there licensing back in the day, jasper reports would have kept up with the current version.

Comment: The license change was done to avoid being eaten: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253925/how-to-avoid-being-forked-into-oblivion-by-a-more-powerful-contributor and http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-136 When JasperSoft was sold to TIBCO, it was reported that JasperSoft had 2000 customers. That is less than the number of paying iText customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, I just found the problem... it was a stupid syntax mistake... it has to be $F{felder} instead of  $F(felder) in my JRExpression... it ist working fine now!